# DevOps release pipeline failed when code pushed on GitHub repository

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I integrate DevOps release pipeline with github but its failed when auto deploy BUT its working when manually deployed please check the attached screen shot

[image]

So when code pushed on master branch then pipeline failed but when I use same Artifacts and manually trigger then its working fine for me

Error in pipeline
[image]

Comment: What kind of agent are you using, Microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent or Deployment Group? If you are using the  self-hosted agent or Deployment Group, you could share the agent version with us.

Comment: On the other hand,  you could try to run the release on Microsoft-hosted agent(e.g. windows-2019) and check if it could work fine.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I am using deployment group. when I stop site in IIS on self server and run pipeline then its work
But site running on IIS then its say extract file failed